# How should I configure app engine task queue to maximize processing speed within rate limit

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-ses

I'm using Google app engine standard (Php) with task queues to process email sending for 15,000 recipients for a single message via Amazon Simple email service (SES). Imposed by SES is a rate limit of 14 messages per second which is the maximum rate I could get at this time.

I'm trying to configure my app.yaml and queue.yaml files to maximize the speed of getting a single email broadcast out to all its recipients while staying within the rate limit.

I have a handler setup to calculate the recipients of each message then it pushes a single task per recipient to another handler that personalizes the message and sends it using the SES api. I need some guidance on what to use as scaling parameters, maximum concurrent requests, bucket size, and rate. From what I understand it's not as simple as setting the task queues processing rate at 14/s.

Answer (score 3):

I'd simply tweak the first handler to:

- only enqueue 14 personalize & send tasks, with no ETA
- enqueue another instance of itself, with a `countdown` of 1 second or, for even tighter "packing", with an ETA exactly 1 second after the moment it **started** its execution

At its next invocation, minimum 1 second later, it'll enqueue another 14 tasks and another instance of itself with ETA, etc., until there are no more addresses to send to. Maybe using queries with cursors to obtain those 14 addresses at each invocation, for example.

I'd use the same queue for both kinds of tasks, to ensure the main handler tasks are never processed before all of the 14 personalize & send tasks enqueue by its predecessor instance started processing.

With such approach you don't need a very precise queue configuration - meeting the SES max rate requirement should be guaranteed by the scheme itself, it just needs a minimum rate configured to allow the scheme to work.

It's worth noting that you should take special care for task failure/retry. Since you're already sending at max rate, any such retry would cause exceeding the max SES rate. So you want to disable such retries, you need to keep track of the addresses for which sending failed and handle them after the main sending sequence finishes.

Comment: that's really clever! in particular that it allows the rate to be controlled through the scheme. Two questions; (1) for clarification, are you suggesting i process 14 recipients in parallel, ie handled together in a single task, using async url fetch or similar? (2) How would you handle a failure that causes the script to abort, so it is unable to chain the next batch of 14?

Comment: For 1) I'd make separate tasks for each recipient, just like you have now. This moves most of the risk of failure to those tasks - I never encountered a failure for just enqueueing a few tasks. For 2), you can also handle re-tries of this particular task (it's not actually sending emails). Even better - make somehow the task enqueueing for the 14 tasks [transactional](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#enqueuing_tasks_in_cloud_datastore_transactions) - this ensures the email sending tasks are enqueued only if the transaction is successful.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and your thoughtful responses. Ill give this a try to start with and adjust if necessary. I think the main concern with enqueueing 14 individual tasks, waiting and  enqueueing another 14 is that if task queue is not  configured well for concurrency  and rate  I end up with 14 serially or near serially executed tasks and a 1 second gap before the next 14 are added. But I have no idea what that actually looks like in practice until I've tried. So will have to monitor and adjust if necessary. Thank you!

Comment: Btw my current implementation is very close to what you described. Except I don't use a timer or cursors. Instead I run the recipient calculator query with a status filter (pending, sending, sent, etc) and a fixed limit of 100 rows. I batch push the tasks to queue transactionally and update status. Then enqueue another iteration immediately unless less than 100 rows were found. So all I need to change is limit to 14, and sleep 1 sec before next iteration is enqueued. Your response was extra valuable in validating my existing approach. Thank you x 2.

Comment: Watch out for [Cursors and data updates](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/query-cursors#cursors_and_data_updates) - you shouldn't *need to* filter on (and thus update) pending/status/sent, the cursor itself should do the job. You only need to keep track of the failures to retry at the end.